# FBX model doesn't display correctly in XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, fbx

I have a 3D FBX model that i want to draw it in XNA 4.0 windows game. [Here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B48B_NK9h0sPR1FQR25HLXAwNXM/edit?pli=1) is the Model in FBX viewer:

But when I run the project, it display like [this](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B48B_NK9h0sPUnZnbVI4ellJWVk/edit?pli=1)

this is my drawing method:

```
private void DrawModel(Model model, Matrix worldMatrix, string name)
    {
        Matrix[] modelTransforms = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
        model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(modelTransforms);
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.World = Matrix.CreateWorld(position, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), Vector3.Up) * worldMatrix;
                effect.View = viewMat;
                effect.Projection = projectionMat;
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
```

And this is base draw method:

```
  protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);

        graphics.GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;


        DrawModel(house, houseWorld, "house");


        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the problem is with your effect.World property. You are doing something odd by creating a matrix, and then combining it with `worldMatrix`. What makes it even odder is that you create the set of absolute transforms (`modelTransforms`), but you don't use them.

Typically, it would look like this:

`effect.World = modelTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * worldMatrix;`

Your `Matrix.CreateWorld(position, Vector3.Backward, Vector3.Up)` looks like a way that you are simply adding some translation (`position`) to the mix. Usually, you would add position to `worldMatrix` before bringing it into the draw(). But, the following might work for you:

`effect.World = modelTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * worldMatrix * Matrix.CreateWorld(position, Vector3.Backward, Vector3.Up);`

I put the `CreateWorld()` last because it appears to hold translation info only and with row majore matricies, you translate last.

Comment: Thanks. I really don't know why I didn't use modelTransforms. I probably have changed something and forgot to correct that.
Anyway I applied your code, but the problem is still remaining.
(Sorry if my English is not good)